# Evaluate restrictiveness of conditions involving little o and big o notation

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics

Which condition is stronger between (a) and (b)? In other words does (a) imply (b), or viceversa? Let $\{\lambda_n\}_n$ be a sequence of real positive numbers.

(a) $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\lambda_n}{\sqrt{n}}=\lambda_0$

[that is equivalent to writing $\frac{\lambda_n}{\sqrt{n}}=O(1)$]

(b) $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\lambda_n}{n}=0$

[that is equivalent to writing $\frac{\lambda_n}{n}=o(1)$]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) is not equivalent to $\lambda_n/\sqrt n = O(1)$, but it is *sufficient* for $\lambda_n/\sqrt{n} = O(1)$. It is possible that $\lambda_n/\sqrt{n} = O(1)$ but that the limit *does not exist*. Consider $\lambda_n = \sqrt n\sin n$, for example.

Now, if $\lambda_n/\sqrt n = O(1)$ then $\lambda_n/n = O(1/\sqrt n) = o(1)$. However if $\lambda_n = n^{3/4}$ then $\lambda_n/\sqrt n \to \infty$ but $\lambda_n/n \to 0$.

Thus $\lambda_n/\sqrt{n} = O(1) \implies \lambda_n / n = o(1)$, but the reverse is not true.